# Insert formatted values as currency type while using EPPlus

Tags: format, currency, epplus

I am using format:

***type ="$###,###,##0.00"***

for currency and assigning the format type to the worksheet cells

eg. 
`wrkSheet.Cells[0].Style.Numberformat.Format = formatType;`

But this is inserted as text type in excel. 
I want this to be inserted as Currency or Number in order to continue to do analysis on the values inserted (sort, sum etc).

Currently as it is text type validations do not hold correct. 
Is there any way to force the type in which the formatted values can be inserted?

Answer (score 15):

Your formatting is correct. You needs to covert values to its native types

### Use this code, it should work:

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
{
    var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sales list - ");
    worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Style.Numberformat.Format = "$###,###,##0.00";
    worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value =Convert.ToDecimal(24558.4780);

    package.SaveAs(new FileInfo(path));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Indices start from 1 in Excel.

This code

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
{
    var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sales list - ");
    worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Style.Numberformat.Format = "$###,###,##0.00";
    worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = 24558.4780;

    package.SaveAs(new FileInfo(path));
}
```

produces **$24 558,48** for me

Comment: It produces $24,558,48. But it is inserted as text in excel. I want it to be entered as Number.

Comment: @user3913190 what is inserted as text (string)? `worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = 24558.4780;` here it is passed as double

Comment: use this 
concert to native type 
worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value =Convert.ToDecimal(24558.4780);