# While downloading the excel file i want the excel cell value will be displaying as currency format which one has currency format

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, epplus

I want to download an excel file which has some column which contains number value, text value and currency value.

Now I want to display the number format on every cell. Every number format works fine except the currency one.

Suppose I have a value $100.00. Now I want to display that value as currency (number format). How can we do this?

Comment: Welcome.  Please don't just paste the body of your question into the title. [ask].  Any code to show?  What have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert formatted values as currency type while using EPPlus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25154383/insert-formatted-values-as-currency-type-while-using-epplus)

Answer (score 1):

Enter the money value as you would a double and enter the format like:

```
 worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Style.Numberformat.Format = "$###,###,##0.00";
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25154383/insert-formatted-values-as-currency-type-while-using-epplus) is a duplicate of your question I believe.